# select Window doesn't close

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a window, it open (programmatically in the code) a paypal window, the title is: `"Se connecter pour terminer le paiement - PayPal"`

I want to close it first, then close our current window, i use the code:

```
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>css=td &gt; h1</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>Se connecter pour terminer le paiement - PayPal</td>
    <td>Se connecter pour terminer le paiement - PayPal</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>close</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=connexion</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

it it says it cannot find the window with title "Se connecter pour terminer le paiement - PayPal", I see it in my html header title though

What can i do?

Comment: check to see what is in the "title" tag, you might have it wrong (not exact). Also take a look at the link that causes this pop up to see if there is an id associated with it, and use that.